# Remove Quotation marks from a dictionary

Tags: python, nltk

I have a dictionary of bigrams, obtained by importing a csv and transforming it to a dictionary:

```
bigram_dict = {"('key1', 'key2')": 'meaning', "('key22', 'key13')": 'mean2'}
```

I want keys' dictionary to be without quotation marks, i.e.:

```
desired_bigram_dict={('key1', 'key2'): 'meaning', ('key22', 'key13'): 'mean2'}
```

Would you please suggest me how to do this?

Comment: You need to parse the string as a tuple.

Comment: Related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using a dictionary comprehension, where you call [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) on the key:

```
from ast import literal_eval
bigram_dict = {"('key1', 'key2')": 'meaning', "('key22', 'key13')": 'mean2'}

res = {literal_eval(k): v for k,v in bigram_dict.items()}
```

Result:

```
{('key22', 'key13'): 'mean2', ('key1', 'key2'): 'meaning'}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [*literal_eval*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) each key and reassign:

```
from ast import literal_eval

bigram_dict = {"('key1', 'key2')": 'meaning', "('key22', 'key13')": 'mean2'}


for k,v in bigram_dict.items():
    bigram_dict[literal_eval(k)] = v
```

Or to create a new dict, just use the same logic with a *dict comprehension*:

```
{literal_eval(k):v for k,v in bigram_dict.items()}
```

Both will give you:

```
{('key1', 'key2'): 'meaning', ('key22', 'key13'): 'mean2'}
```